# I keep getting the warning : Name "main::URLLIST" used only once: possible typo

Tags: regex, perl

Currently I'm learning how use perl following the lessons on

http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/11/begperl3.html.

Ive now come across the metacharacters section and when I run the code in eclipse I get the following error:
Name "main::URLLIST" used only once: possible typo  Metacharacters.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ":5.10"; 

for my $line (<URLLIST>) {
    # "If the line starts with http: and ends with html...."
    if (($line =~ /^http:/) and
        ($line =~ /html$/)) {
        say $line;
    }
}
```

please could you advise on why this is happening.

Comment: why don't you combine both? `if ($line =~ /^http:.*html$/)`

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. And it's because you're apparently trying to read from a file without having opened it.

Answer (score 1):

You're treating `URLLIST` as a file handle, but you never opened it. Just use `<>` instead, and it will read from the file names passed as arguments or from STDIN if no arguments were provided.

Tip: You should use `while (my $line = <>)` instead of `for my $line (<>)` as the latter needlessly loads the entire file into memory before the loop starts.

Comment: Isn't the `for` version of that optimised nowadays?

Comment: Did you mean "the latter" instead of "the former" ?